# DRYing Search Logic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [**search logic**](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) to filter results on company listing page. The user is able to specify any number of parameters using a variety of named URLs. For example:

> /location/**mexico**
>   /sector/**technology**
>   /sector/**financial**/location/**argentina**

Results in the following respectively:

```
params[:location] == 'mexico'
params[:sector] == 'technology'
params[:sector] == 'financial' and params[:location] == 'argentina'
```

I am now trying to cleanup or 'DRY' my model code. Currently I have:

```
def self.search(params)
    ...
    if params[:location]
        results = results.location_permalink_equals params[:location] if results
        results = Company.location_permalink_equals params[:location] unless results
    end
    if params[:sector]
        results = results.location_permalink_equals params[:sector] if results
        results = Company.location_permalink_equals params[:sector] unless results
    end
    ...
end
```

I don't like repeating the searchs. Any suggestions? Thanks.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would write it:

```
[params[:location], params[:sector]].reject(&:nil?).each do |q|
  results = (results ? results : Company).location_permalink_equals q
end
```

There's plenty of other ways, just an idea. Has the benefit of making it easy to add say `params[:street]` or something.

Comment: Use compact instead of reject(&:nil?) -- it should be faster and does the same. You could also try params.values_at(:location, :sector).compact.each...

Comment: Good ideas. I like `reject nil` as it's immediately clear what it does. `values_at` is great, especially if there were more params.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can really DRY that up much when sticking to SearchLogic... I'd suggest to refine your routes to directly emit `*_permalink` as parameter names and do something like this:

```
Company.all :conditions => params.slice(:location_permalink, :sector_permalink)
```

or

```
Company.find :all, :conditions => params.slice(:location_permalink, :sector_permalink)
```

Documentation link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Slice.html